# How to apply new config parameter/ flags to etcd server

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

Team, I have 3 etcd servers running and I need to apply new config by exporting variables to values. But how should I assure they are applied and how to apply after exporting variables?

Basically, I exec into etcdPod and did this but how to assure they take effect?

`export ETCD_MAX_REQUEST_BYTES=1572864`

and

`export ETCD_QUOTA_BACKEND_BYTES=1572864`

Comment: You are silly to think that running `export` in an `kubectl exec` has one iota of influence over a running `etcd`. If it's already a Pod, then `kubectl edit` and put those variables into the `env:` block of the `Deployment` or `StatefulSet` or whatever

Answer (score 1):

I figured out: we need to edit the manifest file of etcd and specify the parameter there. Then kubelet observing that change in manifest will automatically spin the pod again with new values.